# Tcp connection not seen on peer node

Tags: docker, network-interface, tcpdump, ss

I got several nodes to run my software. After startup, I found tcp connection is abnormal between two nodes.

Assume A is the leader which is listening on port 1234, B should connect A.

**On node B, use ss, I can see:**

```
$ss |grep A
tcp    ESTAB      0      0      B:50144                A:1234
```

**But on node A, I can see nothing when run `ss |grep B`.**

As expected, B could not read any data from this connection, which cause my software not work.

Two more details to mention:

- Run tcpdump when kill my software process, I can see packet interaction on both nodes
- There is a bridge named b0, which bridge on eth0, and has the same ip with eth0

My question is: **why is this happen, and how can i fix it.**

Update1:

Run tcpdump

- kill process on node B, B send FIN to A, A reply RESET.
- kill process on node A, A send nothing to B, and vice versa. The connection can be seen from B, even A is not listening on 1234 any more.

Comment: What does `sudo ss -np | grep 1234` report on A?

Comment: @berndbausch `sudo ss -np | grep 1234` shows a lot of tcp connections from other nodes but not B.

Comment: I would think of some misunderstanding or misreading. I can't imagine that B sees an established connection to A that A doesn't see. Perhaps for a few seconds, but not permanently. Does tcpdump show how the connection is closed? It should show it when you run it on A.

Comment: @berndbausch After reviewed the tcpdump data, B send Fin to A, A replied Reset, which means A actually doesn't think the connection exist.

Comment: If I understand what Wikipedia says about [connection termination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination), the RST can be send even for an open connection, though to me it's definitely odd what happens there. I would try to monitor A's connection status while B is connected. Since you are the author, A should be able to log connection requests and connection termination.